# MySQL selecting specific entries from joined table

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-concat, group

I have a table with users' subscriptions to a specific service, billed monthly.
There is also a table of 'suspensions' - with 'from' and 'to' dates to store information about user's temporary suspension of his subscription.

There are three possible cases:

- both 'from' and 'to' dates are in the past - the user had its subscription suspended for a period in the past, but now the subscription is active again
- 'from' is in the past, but 'to' is in the future or is NULL - the service is suspended at the moment (until 'to' date or undefinitely)
- 'from' and 'to' are in the future (or 'from' is in the future and 'to' is NULL) - the user requested a future subscription suspension/cancellation, but at the moment the service is still active

There may be multiple entries in 'suspensions' for a given subscription, some may be already done (in the past), some 'in progress'.

Now I need to select active subscriptions.

I tried to do someting like:

```
SELECT * FROM service 
LEFT JOIN suspensions ON service.id = suspensions.service_id 
WHERE 
  suspensions.id IS NULL 
OR 
  ( suspension_from < CURDATE() AND suspension_to < CURDATE() ) 
OR ( suspenstion_from > CURDATE() AND ( suspension_to > CURDATE() OR suspension_to IS NULL)) ) 
GROUP BY 
   service.customer_id
```

and that works if there's only one entry in 'suspensions' table for a given service.

But if a customer has multiple suspension entries with different outcomes as to present moment, for example from 01-01-2021 to 31-12-2021 and 01-09-2023 to 31-08-2024 then the WHERE clause treats the first one as "active service" (suspension in the past), the second one as "inactive at the moment" (and omits that one as expected) and in the result I have that service as active (because of the first entry), while in fact it is inactive.

How to do this? Somehow count (or concat) "active" results and "inactive" results, group by customer_id and afterwards filter only those, which have 0 inactive results?

Comment: How about the case where there is no entry in the table suspensions for a certain service_id? Is that possible?  (I already see the where suspension_id is null part....). So yes

Comment: If there's no entry in suspensions, then the service is active (was never suspended)

Comment: Yeah, writng a question on a forum somehow relaxes my brain and I find the answer :) I added to the select: SUM(IF ( suspension_from < CURDATE() AND suspension_to < CURDATE(),1,0)) AS past, SUM(IF (suspension_from < CURDATE() AND (suspension_to > CURDATE() OR suspension_to IS NULL),1,0)) AS present, SUM(IF ( suspension_from > CURDATE(),1,0)) AS future.
And now I can make an outer SELECT filtering entries with 'present > 0'

Comment: I would flip the logic around and filter suspensions to list inactive subscriptions only and then use the anti-join (... left join ... where ... is null) to get the ones that are active. Determining the inactive subscription is easier as if you find any rows in the suspensions table that make  a subscription inactive now, then it cannot be in the active list.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY service.customer_id` makes no sense and produces logically incorrect query (and output). It results in only one random non-suspended service returned for each separate customer - or produces an error if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM service 
LEFT JOIN suspensions ON service.id = suspensions.service_id 
WHERE suspensions.service_id IS NULL 
   OR CURRENT_DATE NOT BETWEEN suspension_from AND COALESCE(suspension_to, CURRENT_DATE) 
-- GROUP BY service.customer_id
-- maybe, ORDER BY service.customer_id ?
```